# Deploy to production with git using Acquia like localserver

Tags: drush, version-control, acquia-dev-desktop

I'm using Acquia to export my local proyect to production proyect but when I did git push just the code was saved, the changes that I did in UI was not saved for example I created a user in local UI but it did not reflect in production UI, do I have to use drush to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the database. git only handles files.

So export your local database, and import it in production.
For that you could use [drush sql-sync](https://www.prometsource.com/blog/using-sql-sync-rsync-drush), but you need to set it up properly.

You could also export the database to an .sql file via phpMyAdmin or your preferred db-tool. and then in aquia devcloud, you import that .sql file.